# Cant seem to get printing to work using Print.js, nothing appears when i click print

Tags: javascript, angularjs, printing, printjs

I have just started using http://printjs.crabbly.com/#documentation

and after reading the documentation, it doesnt seem to be giving me a printer preview window when i click print, what is very interesting is that it doesn't seem to be giving me any js errors on the console on chrome. please see below :

```
     <button type="button" onclick("printJS('JobSheet','html')")>Print Job 
     Sheet</button>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('bundles/css/print.min.css')}}">
<script src="{{asset('bundles/js/print.min.js')}}"></script>
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting any errors??check out my [simple](http://plnkr.co/edit/qJk61Y0X2avPv5RBJXpD?p=preview) snippets once and compare with yours.please make sure your referring the correct files of printjs and about the id

```
<p id="myElementId">Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="printJS('myElementId', 'html')">tryprint</button>
```

Comment: got it was using onclick on the wrong way. thanks for your help.

Comment: @Sa E Chowdhary I am trying to print html from react. i am passing the id to print function but nothing happens when i click. Can you help me?

Comment: any errors?? are you loading the js properly?? try to create a online accessable snippet with your problem